# What can I do to solve Google Cloud vm instance network problem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, resources, google-compute-engine, google-iap

The network is working before and I have not change anything on vm. After few months, I can not access the vm instance.

- The vm instance is running
- I will get "Request timed out" when ping to external network ip address.
- I can not access SSH. The SSH port was open properly.
- When troubleshooting my connection status of SSH in browser, it is stuck on Network status.

What should I do to know the reason of problem? After I restart the vm instance few times, it will running normally for a period, but the problem will appear again.

Any idea to make sure the vm instance will not disconnect from external network with this reason again?

[image: Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed - Code: 1006]

[image: Troubleshooting your connection - Stuck at Network status]

[image: Cannot access the vm instance from external network]

Here are the resource consuming of my vm

[image: CPU usage]
[image: Disk usage]

Comment: If restarting the VM solves the problem, then check the following: 1) free disk space, memory utilization, and CPU utilization. My guess is that your VM is over capacity. Edit your question with the configuration and values from my checklist.

Comment: Once the VM instance works properly, Monitor the Memory RAM and CPU utilization.
if the RAM or CPU utilization exceeds the limit. I suggest trying to increase your
VM instance RAM. and Monitor your VM instance if the problem persists.

Comment: After I restart the VM, I can access the vm again. And disk space is used 37%, CPU is using below 20%.

Comment: The internal numbers for the VM look good. Monitor those numbers until the VM becomes non-responsive again.

Comment: May I ask what your machine type config is? what application or is process using this instance?
Try to increase the RAM of your VM instance. Looking at the Cloud Monitoring metrics, it shows OK, since the reboot

Comment: Machine type: g1-small, 0.5-1 vCPU (1 shared core), 1.7 GB Memory, Intel Broadwell. Storage: 40 GB, SCSI, ubuntu-2004-focal-v20220404. I am running a vestacp Docker only and map it to HTTP and HTTPS ports.

Comment: I reviewed the required [specs](https://www.cloudpanel.io/blog/vesta-control-panel/) for the vestacp docker, and your VM instance specs seem okay. but I suspect it is a resource issue. recommend switching to higher N1 machine types [N1 machine series link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#n1_machines). then monitor if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, VESTACP minimum system requirements for VM instances should be okay. But you can also consider the workload process for your VM instance.

I recommend switching to a higher [N1 machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#n1_machines) to provide good performance for the workload and machine requirements.